# Oracle db in UTF-16, Java hibernate webapp in UTF-8, ★ character not persisted

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, encoding, utf-8

I have a webapp written in Java6 + Hibernate (jdbc oracle thin client) + Guice running on tomcat7 + ORACLE 10g. The application is fully encoded in UTF-8, the db is encoded in UTF-16.

From [Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/java.920/a96654/advanc.htm#1003420) I see that the client uses the jvm encoding to send data to the DB. The data is converted on the db and should be persisted correctly. Unfortunately when i try to persist a string containing `★` this is persisted as a reversed question mark.

I tried to set the jvm parameter `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8`, but this didn't work. Any other possible solution?

**UPDATE**:

Given an entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="bean")
public class Bean{
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    //getters and setters
}
```

a service extending [BasePersistentService](https://github.com/patred/Sem/blob/master/src/main/java/it/synclab/patred/sem/services/persistent/BasePersistentService.java) which allows data access,
a "bean" table with two columns:

```
name nvarchar2(200),
surname varchar2(200)
```

The exact use case is as follows:

```
// context initialized, BeanService injected in the variable beanService
Bean p = new Bean();
p.setName("myLittleStar★");
p.setSurname("nope");
beanService.save(p);
```

then on the db:

```
select * from bean;
```

result:

```
name: 'myLittleStar¿'
surname: 'nope'
```

This is the single jdbc resource

```
<Resource name="jdbc/dbConnPool" auth="Container"
    factory="oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl" type="oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource"
    description="Connection Pool DB" connectionFactoryClassName="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
    initialPoolSize="10" minPoolSize="10" maxPoolSize="90" maxStatements="100"
    connectionWaitTimeout="30" inactiveConnectionTimeout="20"
    abandonedConnectionTimeout="600" user="*******" password="*******"
    url="*******" fastConnectionFailoverEnabled="true"
    onsConfiguration="*******" connectionPoolName="UCPPool"
    validateConnectionOnBorrow="true" />
```

This is the relevant part of the hibernate cfg

```
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider">
        org.hibernate.search.store.FSDirectoryProvider
    </property>

    <property name="connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/dbConnPool</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
    <property name="archive.autodetection">class, hbm</property>

</session-factory>
```

I have not found possible configurations to setup encoding in file.

Moreover I have found that it is not possible to configure the encoding in the oracle connection string.

Tell me if I can provide more useful data.

**EDIT 2**:
Replaced the type of the column 'name' in the 'bean' table from varchar2 to nvarchar2, this does not solve the problem but is necessary.

Comment: `file.encoding` won't help here; you have to teach the JDBC driver from Oracle to use the correct encoding. What about you showed some code?

Comment: code coming in about 3h, sorry for the delay

Comment: @Gabber By saying that you effectively doomed the question, soon people will vote to close/down the question because you don't provide any code. I recommend you delete it manually, and undelete it when you have time to put the code in

Comment: I hope that won't happen. I didn't post any code since this is not about the code itself, but about configuration.  Maybe hibernate config files and jdbc config could be helpful, I'll post them as soon as I can.

Comment: @fge showed some code, see anything wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I can't see what's wrong here... :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Horrible but working solution:

Encode the string that needs to be persisted using urlencode, Base64 or the encoding algorithm that better suits your needs. Of course the encoding must produce an output that does not contain characters that can't be persisted on your database.

You can either wrap your entity or change the setter. On getting the entity from the db you must decode the string the other way round.

This is an ugly workaround, but it fixed the problem *locally*.